# Is there a function to swap two segment in a c++ vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, vector, swap

I know there is `std::swap` that can swap two element in a vector, or iteratively swap two segments with the same length. For example, I can write a loop to swap `bcd` and `efg` in the vector `abcdefgh` , resulting in `aefgbcdh`. But can I do swap `bcd` and `ef` (different length)? Or is there any other function in `std::vector` that can achieve this?

Comment: *"Or is there any other function in std::vector that can achieve this"* Note that many classes in the StdLib are designed to offer minimal interfaces. For example, `vector` does not have a `sort` member function because sorting a random access sequence can be implemented as a free function (does not require privileged access nor implementation details).

Comment: Are your segments always adjacent, as `bcd` and `ef` in your example? Or is it possible that you might need to swap `bcd` and `fg`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the segments are adjacent, you can use [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate). For example:

```
std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

Let's say I want to swap the `{ 1, 2, 3 }` with the `{ 4, 5, 6, 7 }`. I can do this:

```
std::rotate(v.begin() + 1, v.begin() + 4, v.begin() + 8);
```

If the segments are not adjacent, you can do it by using `rotate` twice, but it may do more work than is strictly necessary. For example, to swap `{ 1, 2 }` with `{ 4, 5, 6, 7 }`

```
std::rotate(v.begin() + 1, v.begin() + 4, v.begin() + 8);
std::rotate(v.begin() + 5, v.begin() + 7, v.begin() + 8);
```

Comment: @scx: No, that is not correct. The code works as described in the answer.

Comment: Yep, sorry for misleading you.

Answer (score 3):

This reduces to an equal length interval swap followed by a rotate.

The equal length interval swap reduces the problem to 'move an interval to another spot', which can be implemented in-place with `std::rotate`.

If the half open interval `[a,b)` is moving forward to `x`, then:

```
std::rotate( a,b,x );
```

if moving backward to `y` then:

```
std::rotate( y,a,b );
```

If we assume that we can get the intervals in the correct order (left interval before the right in the sequence), then we can do this:

```
template<class I>
void swap(I a, I b, I x, I y){
  using std::distance; using std::next; using std::advance;
  auto d_ab=distance(a,b);
  auto d_xy=distance(x,y)
  auto d=(std::min)(d_ab,d_xy);
  std::swap_ranges(a,next(a,d),x);
  advance(a,d);
  advance(x,d);
  if (a==b){
    std::rotate(b,x,y);
  }else{
    std::rotate(a,b,x);
  }
}
```

micro-optimizations that avoid going over elements more than once can be done, but for vector iterators the extra advances shoukd be next to free.

An industrial strength one would do tag dispatching, write a slick one for random access iterators, and for other iterators do a double iterator loop swap elements (manual swap ranges that bounds checks), with a similar `rotate` at the end.

If we do not know that the order is `a`, `b`, `x`, `y` we need to require random access iterators (and gain access to `<`).  Then we need to wrap the `std::rotate` calls above to change the order of the arguments.

With access to an `end` iterator, we can do it inefficiently with forward iterators still.

Comment: Well, I stopped at that point (checking which range comes first), since I worried about the iterator category. Now you assume RA, so you could actually write some things simpler (e.g. distance, advance). A modular solution might be to order the ranges first in a distinct algorithm.

Comment: @dyp as far as I can tell, I need `end` or `<`.

Comment: end? `<` is only guaranteed for RaIt. The rest should work fine with FwdIt, as far as I can see.

Comment: @dyp with `end` I could search forward from both `y` and `b` until I found `a` `x` or `end` and thereby determine their order.

Answer (score 1):

```
void swap(std::vector<int>& v, int start1, int end1, int start2, int end2)
{
    int size2 = end2 - start2 + 1;
    int size1 = end1 - start1 + 1;
    auto begin = v.begin() + start1;
    auto end = v.begin() + end2 + 1;

    std::rotate(begin, v.begin() + start2, end);
    std::rotate(begin + size2, begin + size2 + size1, end);
}
```

This is a generic version to do the work using double rotate trick :)